# Glyphicons not showing but colleague has the same code

Tags: html, css, glyphicons

My colleague sent me this exact code and on his page the icon (s) do show up.
And on my page they don't. But that's weird because its the same code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Please clarify it.

Comment: Your current link import has some invalid whitespace characters, try replacing(copy-paste) from site directly in order to avoid such errors.

Comment: @Arvind Beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has some invalid white-space characters, try replacing(copy-paste) from site directly in order to avoid such errors.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- won't work -->
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
    <!-- works fine -->
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
</body>

</html>
```